# Как спарсить координаты python selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, selenium

Час добрый

Как на данной странице (https://kvartiry-bolgarii.ru/neveroyatnaya-kvartira-s-vidom-na-more-tip-pentkhaus-o26253) можно при помощи селениума получить координаты от карты, хранящиеся в data-coords ?

Так же по возможности, как можно достать ссылки на все картинки сверху страницы?

Comment: Можно и без селениума достать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно без [selenium](/questions/tagged/selenium) обойтись

Картинки сверху страницы и так приходят с сервера, координаты тоже доступны, просто они дополнительно рендерятся javascript'ом

Накидал пример, но в нем **не** сделал склеивание ссылок на картинки (рекомендую через `rs.url` и `urljoin` сделать, [пример](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/5f333adc169490c9d3d031f929f00c3a9e222ed9/html_parsing/online_south_park_ru/main.py#L67)) и парсинг координат

[Пример:](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/8ebfd5c3610b0c55710fabba617bcd06ec6d6fa7/html_parsing/kvartiry_bolgarii_ru.py#L13)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

rs = requests.get('https://kvartiry-bolgarii.ru/neveroyatnaya-kvartira-s-vidom-na-more-tip-pentkhaus-o26253')
root = BeautifulSoup(rs.content, 'html.parser')

urls = root.select('#slider > li > img[src]')
print(urls)
# [<img alt="" src="/photos/5e2c79b4-7da2-478e-a783-ad8f010d0b15.jpg"/>, ..., <img alt="" src="/photos/90f58624-1f32-46a2-afc9-ad8f010e2703.jpg"/>]

coords = root.select_one('#map[data-coords]')
print(coords['data-coords'])
# 42.6399264:27.6781406
```

Comment: За несколько часов так и не смог разобраться каким образом сшить ссылки вместе, можете подсказать пожалуйста? 
Скорее проблема с тем чтобы из src вытащить часть ссылки

Comment: @Дмитрий, https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/8ebfd5c3610b0c55710fabba617bcd06ec6d6fa7/html_parsing/kvartiry_bolgarii_ru.py#L16